# Find Longitude & Latitude of another point from first point with given distance.

Tags: php, google-maps, gps

I have code which can find distance between two longitude and latitude values. But I want to trace 2nd point's longitude and latitude values when the kilometer, first point's latitude and longitude values are given.

Here is the code, I found to find distance between two points using their latitude and longitude values.

```
<?php
    function getLatLong($address) {
        $address = str_replace(' ', '+', $address);
        $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&sensor=false';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $geoloc = curl_exec($ch);
        $json = json_decode($geoloc);

        return array($json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat, $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lng);
    }

    $address = getLatLong('Guildford');
    $address = getLatLong('BH15 2BT');
    $address = getLatLong('10 Downing Street, London');

    function Haversine($start, $finish) {
        $theta = $start[1] - $finish[1];

        $distance = (sin(deg2rad($start[0])) * sin(deg2rad($finish[0]))) + (cos(deg2rad($start[0])) * cos(deg2rad($finish[0])) * cos(deg2rad($theta))); 
        $distance = acos($distance); 
        $distance = rad2deg($distance); 
        $distance = $distance * 60 * 1.1515;

        return round($distance, 2);
    }

    $start = getLatLong('Guildford');
    $finish = getLatLong('BH15 2BT'); 
    $distance = Haversine($start, $finish);

    print('<p>The distance between ['.$start[0].', '.$start[1].'] and ['.$finish[0].', '.$finish[1].'] is '.$distance.' miles ('.($distance * 1.609344).' km).</p>');
?>
```

But, I need to find 2nd point's longitude and latitude from 1st point's longitude and latitude and distance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This webpage](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) is very very useful for this kind of things.

If you go there, you'll find that the latitude of your new point is given by:

```
asin( sin(φ1)*cos(d/R) + cos(φ1)*sin(d/R)*cos(θ) )
```

and the longitude of your new point is given by:

```
λ1 + atan2( sin(θ)*sin(d/R)*cos(φ1), cos(d/R)−sin(φ1)*sin(φ2) )
```

where φ1 is the latitude of your old point, φ2 the latitude of your new point, λ1 the longitude of your old point, θ is the bearing (in radians, clockwise from north), d is the distance travelled, R is the earth’s radius. By old point I mean the first point, the one you know the coordinates.

If you don't know the earth radius, you can use its mean radius: 6371000m (watch out for the units) or [compute an approximation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20200/how-do-you-compute-the-earths-radius-at-a-given-geodetic-latitude) depending on the latitude.

Comment: If it does not, show some data example you are using and I will take a deeper look...

Comment: Yes, I am stuck with bearing. I don't know what value to feed in there. Thanks

Comment: Do you know in which direction the gps or user moved from the first point? This is the bearing, it should be converted into radian.

Comment: If you don't have this value, with only a distance, your point 2 could be anywhere on a circle. (the distance is the radius of this circle and point 1 its center .)    or maybe you have a road or path that the point must follow?

Comment: Yes, Exactly I would need that whole circle. Acutally what i am coding is finding user from my location to within 5 km of that area, and yes, this will be circle from my point.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide me solution for my app. Thanks

Comment: So you are not looking for a coordinate, but for all the users that are within a radius of a known position. (i.e. all the users that are 5 km or less to a point) ?

Comment: Yes. that was my main target to achieve.
Thanks